# Yourself vs Yourselves

Tags: grammatical-number

Which of the following is correct-

- Keep those smiles to yourself

or

- Keep those smiles to yourselves

When referring to more than one person

Comment: You _can_ address a plural audience in the singular, of course: 'Mind you don't cut yourself' could certainly be said when addressing a class of young craft students. It's the 'individual/personal touch'. But you'd probably use 'Keep that smile to yourself' here, and the plural would probably be preferable with this example in any case: the hedged plural admonition.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I tried googling a number of variants of hedged (plural) admonitions and found nothing. Is there a different term for this?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth good point

Comment: @medica It's not a compound! _Hedged_ = put/said in a more polite / less abrasive / more acceptable way (using accepted ways of phrasing, tone etc). Addressing the congregation rather than Fred about their drinking habits is usually kinder.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - ah, I should have known.:( This was just a more learned comment, so to speak. Makes sense, thanks very much! (smiling to myself now...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're referring to the smiles of more than one person, then you are addressing more than one person.

In the event of a foreseeable danger to multiple persons, you would say

> brace yourselves for impact...
>   prepare yourselves for freezing temperatures...
>   you will be exposing yourselves to high heat...

Similarly, *keep those smiles to yourselves* is something exasperated teachers might say to their students.

Answer (score 3):

Yourselves would be the appropriate choice here since smiles is plural. If you were to refer to a single person's smile, you would then use yourself.

Comment: Or if one person were collecting multiple smiles, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of my personal notes:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Post only text or else it cannot be searched. It is also not accessible to screen readers.

Comment: @tchrist Ok, but if I had not posted this then I would have not posted anything. I guess something is better than nothing.